# ComboBox doesn't show items added in a separate thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, lambda

I'm loading items (strings) into a combobox in a separate thread. When loading is done, the combo seems empty. However, if I start typing the name of an existing item into it and then hit the down or up arrow, it autocompletes my item, and suddenly I see all of my items in the combo. What am I doing wrong?
Note: myItem is just a class we created with a public property called Name, and getItems returns an array of these items.

```
    void cmb_GotFocus(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmb.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GetItems));
            thread.Start();
        }
    }

    private void GetItems()
    {
        try
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action(() => cmb.Items.Clear()));

            myItem[] items = Library.GetItems();
            if (items != null && items.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (myItem item in items)
                {
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => cmb.Items.Add(item.name)));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not get items.\nError: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you have a ObservableCollection in your vm and bind the combobox itemssource to it. Then add new items to the observablecollection?

Comment: Thanks Johan, I'll try that. If I could find a solution that leaves the code as it is I'll prefer that - seems much more intuitive to me.

Comment: It may be that the instance of the UI and the instance of the thread are 2 different ones. So you can not see  the data.

Comment: Your code worked for me

Comment: Thanushka - what do you mean by "different instances"? the code is in the same class and assembly. I am not following you...
Mehmet - I am using VS 2010 and .Net 4.0 client profile. What are you using?